# Yii Curl request token from paypal not working

Tags: curl, paypal, yii, token, yii1.x

i am trying to get the paypal token via curl on my Yii project.
The curl extension is already in place (main.php as well). I am using this one: https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-curl

The response is always empty. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Postman returns a token successfully with the curl settings below.

```
$clientId = "xxxxxx";
$secret = "xxxxxxx";

$output = Yii::app()->curl->setOptions(array(
        'CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS' => 'grant_type=client_credentials',
        'CURLOPT_USERPWD'=> $clientId.":".$secret,
        'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER' => 'true',
        'CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER' => 'false"',
        'CURLOPT_HEADER' => 'false',
        'CURLOPT_URL' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
        'CURLOPT_POST' => 'true',
        ))
    $json = json_decode($output);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `setOptions()` which does not send any request and does not return result. You need to call `post()` if you want to send request:

```
$output = Yii::app()->curl
    ->setOptions([
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$clientId:$secret",
    ])
    ->post('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', [
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
    ]);
```